# ZURB Foundation npm build not creating `dist` directory

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I've followed the directions at http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#command-line-tool.html and there is no `dist` directory created. There are several `dist` directories scattered throughout the sub-folders, but not one unified directory with all the files in it.

I've tried both `npm start` and `npm run build`.

How do I get the `dist` directory created?

Comment: Same issue here. I've used Foundation in the past and it's always worked. I followed the docs, but none of the `foundation watch`, `npm start` or other commands start up a web server, or create the `/dist` directory.